# Flet Python - How to move callbacks out of main

Tags: python, flutter, module, filesystems, flet

I'm looking to re-structure my flet app in a more OOP method as I increase the number of features.

How can I move things like callbacks out of my `main()` function when I use them in `flet.Checkbox` I can't add arguments (like `page=page`) to the callbacks.

For example, here is my darkmode callback that when a user checks a box.
I'd like to have a file called `callbacks.py` where I can put my `dark_mode_callback` (and a lot of others) - and then import the module

```
import flet

def main(page):

    settings = {'dark_mode': False}

    def dark_mode_callback(_):
        page.theme_mode = flet.ThemeMode.DARK if dark_mode_checkbox.value else flet.ThemeMode.LIGHT
        page.update()

    dark_mode_checkbox = flet.Checkbox(label="Dark Mode", value=settings.get('dark_mode', False), on_change=dark_mode_callback)

    settings_controls = flet.Row([dark_mode_checkbox])
    page.add(settings_controls)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    flet.app(target=main)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked it out, I can use a settings object to add the various page information. `e` is the event.

```
import flet

class Settings:
    def __init__(self, page):
        self.page = page
        self.settings = {'dark_mode': False}

    def dark_mode_callback(self, e):
        self.page.theme_mode = flet.ThemeMode.DARK if self.dark_mode_checkbox.value else flet.ThemeMode.LIGHT
        self.page.update()

def main(page):
    settings = Settings(page)
    settings.dark_mode_checkbox = flet.Checkbox(label="Dark Mode", value=settings.settings.get('dark_mode', False), on_change=settings.dark_mode_callback)
    settings_controls = flet.Row([settings.dark_mode_checkbox])
    page.add(settings_controls)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    flet.app(target=main)
```